# jQuery: Read values from SoundCloud json in dom var

Tags: jquery, json, soundcloud

For a greasemonkey script I want to read a value from the SoundCloud API.

All API data is added to the DOM in

```
<script>
  var _scPreload = {
    "data": {
```

https://soundcloud.com/im-a-house-gangster/kid-enigma-the-blessing-of-4

That's too complex for me. I'm not sure how to get the value of "created_at" (inside data > models/audible).

Here's a bad test: http://jsfiddle.net/0g78fy52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its more a question about accessing objects/arrays in js.

That should work.

```
$(function() {
    var date = _scPreload['data']['models/audible'][0]['created_at'];   
    $('#result').append(date);
});
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/kqox9ejy/

http://lab.sourcloud.com/stackoverflow/26236951/

More Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects